# Why ({__proto__: []}) return the result of the type of Array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, the following gives the result of false:

```js
({ a: [] } instanceof Array);
console.log(({ a: [] } instanceof Array));
```

the following gives the result of true:

```js
({ __proto__: [] } instanceof Array);
console.log(({ __proto__: [] } instanceof Array));
```

Why are the results different?

Comment: You asked this very same question only minutes ago...

Comment: *nearly the same* ... well, so are `console.log(!true)` and `console.log(true)` they are *nearly the same* and output different results - that's the problem with *nearly* ... it doesn't mean *exactly*

Comment: I suggest you read up on [`__proto__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto)

Comment: While the other question looks very similar, this is fundamentally a very different issue.

Comment: Because `a` is a property with no special meaning, unlike `__proto__`?

Answer (score 0):

```
({ a: [] } instanceof Array);
```

returns false because you are asking if the object initialised with a property that is an array, is itself an array. Obvious answer, no, and the console.log is false.

```
({ __proto__: [] } instanceof Array);
```

asks if an object created with an object initialiser, that sets the first object in its inheritance chain to an empty array (by setting the `__proto__` property of the object being initialised to an empty array) is an instance of Array.

The answer is true because the JavaScript `instanceof X` operator merely reports
if the prototype property of `X` (in this case `Array.prototype`) is in the inheritance chain of the object on the left of the `intanceof` operator. Since the second example object contains an Array object in its inheritance chain, which itself inherits from `Array.prototype`, the answer is `true`.

JavasScript is not a class based language in the classical sense, and `instance of` reports on the inheritance chain of an object, which in most, but not all, cases reflects the notion of `instanceof` in a classical class based language.

Comment: They are all keys in an object, 'a' and '\_\_proto__', so what is the difference? I am confused.

Comment: `__proto__` is not a key in the object, it is a setter and getter for the internal prototype chain pointer, often notated as the " [[prototype]] slot" of an object. Reading properties that are not "own"  local properties of an object searches  the prototype chain for them. Check out "how does javascript prototypal inheritance work" and similar subjects.